# How to implement date range for bar chart

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, data-visualization, bar-chart, date-range

I have generated a bar chart in plotly. Every bar corresponds to a a date in x-axis. How can I implement something of a date picker widget of sort, so that I can see the bar for a particular date or for a range of dates. Is there any module already available for this job. And also could the same solution be applicable for a sunburst chart.

[image]

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/

Comment: @RobRaymond its not working for sunburst chart since there is no xaxes to update upon. Any suggestions to implement the same for sunburst chart?

Comment: your question - is how to do a date picker for a bar chart?  If question is different I recommend you update your question to what it should be along with what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### part 1 - Bar chart with "date picker"

- create some sample data for plotting
- simple case of using https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({**{"date":pd.date_range("1-apr-2021", periods=100)}, **{c:np.random.uniform(i,i+1, 100) for i,c in enumerate(list("abc"))}})

px.bar(df, x="date", y=list("abc")).update_layout(xaxis={"rangeslider":{"visible":True}})
```

[image]

#### part 2 - date picker on sunburst

- using sample data again, assuming date picker applies to rows that form part of sunburst
- use **dash** https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/datepickerrange
- simple **callback** to filter data in plot

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash

app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id="date-picker",
            start_date=df["date"].min(),
            end_date=df["date"].max(),
            display_format="MMMM Y, DD",
        ),
        dcc.Graph(id="sunburst-fig"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("sunburst-fig", "figure"),
    [Input("date-picker", "start_date"), Input("date-picker", "end_date")],
)
def update_graph(start_date, end_date):
    if start_date:
        dfp = df.loc[df["date"].between(*pd.to_datetime([start_date, end_date]))]
    else:
        dfp = df

    fig = px.sunburst(dfp.assign(day=df["date"].dt.strftime("%a"), month=df["date"].dt.strftime("%b")),
            path=["month","day"], values="a")
    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #     app.run_server(debug=True)
    app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

[image]